# Facetime & iMessage: Could not sign in please check network connection

Tags: iphone, ios, messages, facetime

Whenever I try to sign in to iMessage or Facetime on iOS 7.1.2, I always
 get the same message: "Could not sign in. Please check your network connection and try again." 
I have already looked on Apple Discussions before and I have tried several things, including resetting all settings, resetting network settings, even resetting my phone to no luck. I don't know if it's my phone, my Apple ID, or something else. Please help!

Thanks!

I have an iPhone 4 running iOS 7.1.2.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  Does your iPhone have a network or cellular connection?  Can you log into iCloud.com with your Apple ID and password?

Comment: My iPhone is connected to WiFi and has no cellular connection. I can log in to iCloud.com just fine.

Comment: Does your phone usually not have a cell connection (SIM pulled out, for example)? Does the same thing happen on a different Wi-Fi connection?

Comment: My phone normally doesn't have a cell connection, but I have not tried it on different networks.

Comment: Also, adding on to my first comment, I have cellular off, but airplane mode off too, so I just have dots, blank or filled, in the status bar. Adding on to my second comment, I have a SIM card in my iPhone.